# Opening a contextmenu on a listview only if NO item has been clicked

Tags: c#, listview, contextmenu

So thanks to many answers on stackoverflow we all know how to open a contextmenu when an item in a listview has been rightclicked. i.e.:

```
private void listviewItems_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    ListView tmp_SenderListView = sender as ListView;
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) {
        ListViewItem tmp_SelectedItem = tmp_SenderListView.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);
        if (tmp_SelectedItem != null) {
            tmp_SelectedItem.Selected = true;
            contextMenuStripItem.Show(tmp_SenderListView, e.Location);
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to open another (a different) contextmenu when the user clicks inside the listview but does not click on an item but rather the empty space. (preferably does not trigger when clicking on the column header)

My first thoughts were to just test if the above mentioned *tmp_SelectedItem* was *null* and thus no item. when I did however insert the else case and switched it around:

```
private void listviewItems_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    ListView tmp_SenderListView = sender as ListView;
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) {
        ListViewItem tmp_SelectedItem = tmp_SenderListView.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);
        if (tmp_SelectedItem == null) {
            contextMenuStripNoItem.Show(tmp_SenderListView, e.Location);
        }
        else {
            tmp_SelectedItem.Selected = true;
            contextMenuStripItem.Show(tmp_SenderListView, e.Location);
        }
    }
}
```

It didn't work, just hasn't opened anything then.
I tried again, this time opening the *contextMenuStripNoItem* before I tested if an item has been clicked, if that was the case, the *contextMenuStripNoItem* would be closed and the *contextMenuStripItem* would open. This did not work either.

I tried with making the *contextMenuStripNoItem* the main contextMenuStrip of the listView however then it only opened the *contextMenuStripNoItem* no matter where or at what I clicked inside the listView. For addition I tried closing that assigned contextMenuStrip when an item has been clicked and instead opening the other one. Did not work aswell.

I really don't get why it didn't work with the first two approaches, so after some research to confirm there was no tutorial for this or an already existing question on a forum (atleast as far as I searched and understood), I decided to turn to stackoverflow.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (I changed logic a little bit, if you are clicking on an item, it will be selected, so you don't need to check X and Y positions. If checked; show **menustrip1** , if not; so right click not performed on items, show **menustrip2**). You can use `Mouse_Up` event which triggers all over `listbox` mouse events. `Mouse_Click` only works when item got hit.

```
 private void listView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ListView tmp_SenderListView = sender as ListView;
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {

                if (tmp_SenderListView.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    contextMenuStrip1.Show(tmp_SenderListView, e.Location);
                }
                else
                {
                    contextMenuStrip2.Show(tmp_SenderListView, e.Location);
                }
            }
        }
```

Hope helps,

Comment: So I have tried your solution now and it works just like the other one, but why does it not work if I put the if inside the MouseClick Event?

Comment: @RememberOfLife As I told you, `Mouse_Click` only works when user hit an item's label inside ListView.

Comment: So apparently it instantly opens if I click the area with no items, and only opens on release if I click an item. No problem for me. Thanks :)

Comment: Oh well I thought that it would also trigger on empty space since its part of the control right?

Comment: @RememberOfLife you can check here [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview_events(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @RememberOfLife Sorry I was editing :). Not works with that way. I am glad to hear that your problem solved. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code snippet

```
private void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            e.Cancel = true;

    }
```

Comment: This should be the code for the event of the contextMenuStrip that opens when no item is clicked or the one that opens when an item has been clicked on?

Comment: This is the contextMenuStrip Open event